# SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: created_at

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a database with a foreign key but I kept getting the error of `no such column: created_at`, even tho I'm not using created_at somewhere in my code. I wonder why and how to patch this issue.

```js
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
    myhash: Sequelize.TEXT,
  mysalt: Sequelize.STRING,
  keyword: Sequelize.STRING,
})
  , Company = sequelize.define('company', {
    keyword: Sequelize.STRING
  });

User.belongsTo(Company);

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
    myhash: Sequelize.TEXT,
  mysalt: Sequelize.STRING,
  keyword: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {underscored: true})
  , Company  = sequelize.define('company', {
    uuid: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  });

User.belongsTo(Company);
```

Answer (score 1):

created_at is automatically created for keeping the timestamp. You need to set the timestamp option to false like below to all your model definitions.

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
    myhash: Sequelize.TEXT,
  mysalt: Sequelize.STRING,
  keyword: Sequelize.STRING,
},{
timestamps: false
})
```